# What is the function of = sign in this particular closure statement?

Tags: swift, closures

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of closure. I saw this code online:

```
var sayHelloClosure: () -> () = {
    print("hello from closure")
}
```

when I remove the = sign, the compiler output the error message:

```
Missing return in a function expected to return '() -> ()'
```

Could someone please tell me the use of = in this particular context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break that statement down:

```
var sayHelloClosure
```

Ok, we're creating a mutable variable

```
: () -> ()
```

It has a type of `() -> ()`, a function with no arguments that returns `void`.

```
=
```

It's being set to something

```
{
    print("hello from closure")
}
```

And that thing is a closure (basically a unnamed function) that takes no arguments and returns nothing (`void`)

Basically you now have a variable that points to a function that does what's in those braces.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I was struggling to understand it for near a hour. and now everything makes perfect sense. Thanks again for yoru help!

Comment: No problem, it can be a confusing concept at first.